# What is the difference between IPv4 and IPv6 in terms of binary?

Tags: networking, ipv6, ipv4

I have done some research on IPv4 and how to convert IP addresses to binary and vice versa. I also understand that IPv6 contains 4 x the amount of IPv4 binary per section. I just need to thoroughly understand how it works?

Answer (score 2):

The [Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ip_address) on IP Addresses actually has a nice image showing exactly that:
[image]
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Ipv6_address.svg

Hope that helps.